# How to get data into an Arraylist in a collection in the Firestore Database?

Tags: android, firebase, android-studio, arraylist, google-cloud-firestore

i m using cloud firestore database and i have an collection which is named Jobpost1. i want to get data from this collection and store in arraylist.

my java code

```
List<Jobpost> mList = new ArrayList<>();  //this is my arraylist
private CollectionReference collectionReference=db.collection("Job Post1");

 @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();

        collectionReference.get()
                .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(QuerySnapshot queryDocumentSnapshots) {
                        if (!queryDocumentSnapshots.isEmpty()){
                            for (QueryDocumentSnapshot journals: queryDocumentSnapshots){

                            }

                        }else {

                            noJournalEntry.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                        }
                    }
                })
                .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {

                    }
                });

    }
```

[image: database]

Comment: So you want to get the value of the `location` property which is `Vishrantwadi pune` within a single document or within all documents?

Comment: all documetns which present in Jobpost1 and thier fields where want store in arraylist @Alex Mamo

Comment: Have you tried JunaidKhan's answer?

Answer (score 1):

You can populate list this way

```
    List<Jobpost> mList = new ArrayList<>();  //this is my arraylist
    private CollectionReference collectionReference=db.collection("Job Post1");

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();

        collectionReference.get()
                .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(QuerySnapshot queryDocumentSnapshots) {
                        if (!queryDocumentSnapshots.isEmpty()){
                            for (QueryDocumentSnapshot journals: queryDocumentSnapshots){
                                 JobPost jobPost= journals.toObject(JobPost.class);
                                 mList.add(jobPost);
                            }
                        }else {
                            noJournalEntry.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        }
                    }
                })
                .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {

                    }
                });

    }
```